# Dealing with timeseries gaps in Chaco

Tags: python, matplotlib, chaco

I have a standard financial timeseries of data which has gaps for when the market is closed.

The problem is [Chaco](http://code.enthought.com/projects/chaco/) displays these gaps, I could use a formatter in matplotlib as follows and apply to the x-axis to get around this but I am unsure what I should do about this in Chaco.

In matplotlib:

```
class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def __init__(self, dates, fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'):
        self.dates = dates
        self.fmt = fmt

    def __call__(self, x, pos=0):
        'Return the label for time x at position pos'
        ind = int(round(x))
        if ind>=len(self.dates) or ind<0: return ''

        return self.dates[ind].strftime(self.fmt)
```

What would be the efficient way to implement this in Chaco?
Thanks

Comment: With the caveat that I don't know Chaco, I expect that you'd want to use a 2D plot rather than an XY plot.  The fundemental concept of an XY plot is that is to illustrate the relationship between continuous 'X" values.  Just a guess, good luck!

Comment: I can't see why this issue has been tagged as matplotlib?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173632/python-chaco-axis-labels-time-formatting

Comment: Why don't you apply a [mask](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) to your data using `numpy` and then just plot the masked array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the parameters like this

```
from enthought.chaco.scales.formatters import TimeFormatter
TimeFormatter._formats['days'] = ('%d/%m', '%d%a',)
```

Comment: Generating a NAN series using Pandas Timeseries is another way to go [link] http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html[/link].